# In what book can I learn the mathematical theory of times series?

Tags: time-series

In what book can I learn the mathematical theory of times series?

I know times series is always taught in statistics courses, so a lot of other mathematical fields may omit this in their textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the introductory level, I recommend [Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387953515) by Peter J. Brockwell and Richard A. Davis. This book is used in the math dept in my university.

For the advanced level, [Time Series Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691042896) by James Douglas Hamilton and [Time Series: Theory and Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441903194)  by Peter J. Brockwell and Richard A. Davis are very demanding in your mathematical background.

Another is [Econometrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691010188) by Fumio Hayashi. Although it is a book about econometrics, it contains very rigorous treatment on time series in the latter half of the book.

Comment: You might as well get good answers at this site: [Quantitative Finance beta](http://quant.stackexchange.com/).